# HTML object tag not displaying pdf file on localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: html, pdf, xampp

I want to display pdf file on web page with  tag. It’s working well on normal directory and live server.

```
<object style="width:450px;height:380px" data="admissionform.pdf"></object>
```

[Screenshot of Output in normal directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbDnY.jpg)

But same file and same code when I replace it on localhost. The pdf file not displaying. The browser or download manager switching to download the pdf file.

[Screenshot of Output in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfJxp.png)

Comment: Try disabling your download manager.

Comment: If I disable download manager. Then browser download manager will enable

Answer (score 1):

```
<object style="width:450px;height:380px" data="admissionform.pdf"></object>
```

Today I run my script on a localhost on a Linux desktop PC. And the pdf file is displaying well.

But still, Now I try to find out why my embed pdf with HTML object tag is not working in windows operating system